# Bash - issue creating 'goto' equivalent

Tags: linux, bash, function, eval, goto

I'm converting a series of csh scripts to bash as they need to work on two different systems. Currently the scripts work on one system but not the other properly. The conversion to bash is required so they will work on both. In addition, there are some specific coding required for the scripts to work on one system (this doesn't affect how it runs on the other).

So far all the converted scripts work fine, but I've now got a script which has a 'goto' function in it. Since bash doesn't have a 'goto' equivalent, I've been trying to find a solution that works.

The script has a number of start and end options which are pulled from a separate config file. These then allow the script to start and stop at different points. For example:

start: POINT_A/POINT_B
end: POINT_B/POINT_C

This means that the script could start at POINT_A or B, but POINT A can end at B or C, or POINT_B can only end at C. The script has more points than this, but this should explain what the script needs to do.

I found a function that appears to work, but has 'eval' in it and apparently this is a bad code and shouldn't be used. It also appears to conflict with some  if statements (ie. the coding is ignored and an error occurs). I'm looking for a better solution than the one I have so far:

```
begin=$1
finish=$2

function jumpto 
{
    label=$1
    cmd=$(sed -n "/$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
    eval "$cmd" 
    exit
}
start=${begin:-"start"}
end=${finish:-"end"}
jumpto $start

POINT_A:
echo "start at POINT_A"
# point_a coding here
if [ $end == "POINT_B" ]; then
    echo "Done POINT_A commands, finished working before POINT_B"
    exit 0
else
    jumpto POINT_B
fi
POINT_B:
echo "start at POINT_B"
# point_b coding here
if [ $end == "POINT_C" ]; then
    echo "Done POINT_B commands, finished working before POINT_C"
    exit 0
else
    jumpto POINT_C
fi
POINT_C:
echo "all finished"
```

The coding that is ignored are if statements which occur as part of point_x coding. These can either be:

```
if [ $var1 == yes ]; then
  xxxx
else
  :
fi

if [ ! -e $var1 ]; then
  xxxx
else
  :
fi
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the function to work as expected and get the if statements recognised?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it's time to [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your script.  Figuring out how to implement "goto" in a language that doesn't include that instruction will generate headaches in managing the code in the future.  Better to redesign things so you don't need it.  That said, consider `continue` and `break`, along with `trap`.  Not as flexible as csh's `goto`, but they may help you get where you want to go.

Comment: It should be simple to wrap the region with gotos as a loop which contains `case $LABEL`. Ugly as **** but prettier than what you have now... Btw, you could use `exec` instead of `eval`-`exit`, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to recreate `goto`. You can emulate structured control flow statements like `if` and `while` with `goto`, but trying to do the reverse will end in sadness. Instead, figure out how to rewrite the logic so it doesn't require `goto`s.

```
if [[ $start == POINT_A ]]; then
    echo point A stuff
fi

echo point B stuff

if [[ $end == POINT_B ]]; then
    exit
fi

echo point C stuff
```